# How to merge many images into a single large composite image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, composition, tiles, panorama

I have a series of images (around 60) that need to be merged into a singular very large image.  The images were taken from screenshots of a much larger map and so they just need to be stitched back together into a singular large image for a very large output.

So far I've tried a few options, but they all seem panoramic-centric and thus they all do not merge quite right in that they leave artifacts (strange bends and so forth).  Even Photoshop's Photomerge isn't working out (it actually hangs each time with some kind of an apparent bug that's been around since 2013).

What would be the preferred method of stitching such images together that are simply one big set of randomly offset tiles and don't have to account for lens distortions or color correction?

I'm thinking that there may even be a solution via ImageMagick or another open source tool, but since the images do not have direct offsets and were captured in a semi-random fashion simple tiling doesn't work.

This can be done visually rather easily, but it's lengthy and tedious... and this is actually a relatively small project.  I have more than a dozen of these to do with more than 100 tiles each after I get this first one under my belt.

Comment: Chances are you'll spend more time looking for an automated solution that it takes to simply do it visually.

Comment: Photoshop has a built in Automation for Photomerge that I've used before. It's not so bad to use and had good results. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-panoramic-images-photomerge.html

Comment: @ispaany right, it would be good, but I've tried it 10 times with the same hang result each time and then after digging about it appears that this issue (unknown really) has plagued it since 2013 with no actual resolution, so it's a disappointment to say the least.

Comment: I'd have a look at [Autopano](http://www.kolor.com/autopano/)... but it's a bit pricey if you're only ever going to use it once.

Comment: Why not consider some stand alone "stitching" software? Maybe one of these, for example, might suffice: https://beebom.com/photo-stitching-software/